# Invalid login at Login page with entered details on front end

Tags: login, admin-login

Actually, I can login with social logins like Gmail, Facebook. Login working successfully.

But, when i entered the correct details of my login email , password it will be show invalid details.

please find the below figure to understand easily.

[image]

Comment: which version you used in magento?

Comment: magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara, can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check whether you have installed any login related extension in your store.

if yes, disable that by going

```
app->etc->modules -> your extension -> local.xml  set true to false.
```

if not,

2. In root of magento, you can see index.php file, you can un comment these lines in that file : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` ,

Then you can see the real errors that causing the problem

Comment: thanks for reply. yes, i installed login with phone extension. i downloaded from magento connect manager. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-mobile-login.html

Comment: ok disable that through root folder or through admin panel. then check once whether you can login with user details or not. let me know

Comment: yes. working with details thanks. i am login now with email id. but i want to login with phone. thats why i installed this plugin. tell me how? thanks for  responce.

Comment: ok. if you want to login with mobile or any other user name you can use this https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username extension. but becareful with extensions. please accept answer if it helpful